# Sum 5 or more in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

Without using HAVING, how can I get the SQL results to display sum in COUNT column only if the totals are 5 or more?
  [image]

```
SELECT DISTINCT
[ID],
COUNT(CASE WHEN [ICN] >=5 THEN 1 END) AS 'COUNT'

FROM DBO.[OFD]
WHERE [YEAR] = 2018
AND [LOCATION-ID] = '0021'

GROUP BY [ID],
[ICN]
```

When I enter the following code, I get results similar to the example below...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
[ID],
[ICN]

FROM DBO.[OFD]
WHERE [YEAR] = 2018
AND [LOCATION-ID] = '0021'


GROUP BY [STUDENT-ID],
[INCIDENT-NO]
```

[Example of Results I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmlRi.jpg)
[Example of Results I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YqK9.jpg)

Comment: Your example seems incomplete. What is the reference to INNO? Is that the InnoDB engine that is for MySQL?

Comment: @MikePoole, can you write the equivalent query using HAVING, so that we can see what you really need as filters, output cols, etc.?

Comment: Why are you avoiding `HAVING`?

Comment: Hi @DanielCuadra I am not the OP. I am trying to figure out what they want as well.

Comment: The strange requirement of not using HAVING makes this sound like homework or an interview question.

Comment: @SeanLange It's neither.  I am not taking a database class, nor any classes that require scripting, nor interviewing for any positions.

Comment: @Bohemian because I need all of the records, in the results.  When I use HAVING, my results are cut to less than half, because it is only displaying the rows that amount to 5 or more.  As for using [INNO], I did not consider InnoDB.  I was just using [INNO] to shorten the column name.

Comment: @MikePoole Please see my response to Bohemian.  It explains why I used [INNO] in the example.

Comment: Then why the strange requirement to not use HAVING? The point of the having clause is to filter aggregated data. What you really need to do is provide us with enough information so we can help. This is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange Please see the update, above.

Comment: I am guessing you didn't actually read that article. Where is the sample data? Where is the table definition? The point is to make it easy for us to help you. That means making so we don't have to take a picture of your data and type it all out so we have sample data to work with.

Comment: @SeanLange I attempted to enter the examples of the data, but (I guess because I am a new user) it wasn't formatted correctly.  That is why I entered the attached images.

Comment: The idea is for you to provide the table definition and sample data so we can create the table on our system. Using an image of data means many people (myself included) are going to move on. I have no desire to type in your sample data so I can then spend time working on the query. Post the details and we can help you format it.

Comment: @SeanLange Okay.  I have never used this Convert CSV site, but I understand what you are saying.  Thank you.

Comment: You don't need that. Just post a create table statement and some insert statements. Keep it simple.

Comment: @SeanLange I've added it.  Thank you.

Comment: I think you missed it. The problem you are having is the query that gets your results. Great that you showed us what you are getting and what you want but what you really need help with is the original query right?  That is the table(s) and data we need. In your case the table OFD.

Comment: @SeanLange I think I am going to continue working on this on my own.  I appreciate your advice.

Comment: If you took the 5 minutes it would take to post details that are useful this would be answered already. The query itself is pretty straight forward. But best of luck.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks.

Comment: To everyone that attempted to help... I completed the script (on my own) and retrieved the 7,000+ records that I needed.  I appreciate those of you who kindly offered your help.  I just needed to think it through, thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query.  Hopefully this may help

```
;WITH cte_data (id,NumberOfrows)
AS
(
SELECT ID, COUNT(*)NumberOfrows
FROM DBO.[OFD] t 
WHERE [YEAR] = 2018
AND [LOCATIONID] = '0021'
AND INNO>=5
GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT DISTINCT t.id, isnull(NumberOfrows ,0) NumberOfrows
FROM DBO.[OFD] t
LEFT JOIN cte_data t1 on t1.id = t.id
WHERE t.[YEAR] = 2018
AND t.[LOCATIONID] = '0021'
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.  I am getting back results with numbers below 5.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check <5 and use sum instead of count

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  [ID],
  SUM(CASE WHEN [INNO] >=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'COUNT'
FROM DBO.[OFD]
WHERE [YEAR] = 2018
  AND [LOCATION-ID] = '0021'
GROUP BY [ID],[INNO]
```

changed to

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  SUM(CASE WHEN [INNO] >=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'COUNT'
FROM DBO.[OFD]
WHERE [YEAR] = 2018
  AND [LOCATION-ID] = '0021'
```

Comment: I tried that, before I posted.  The results are all 0s and 1s.  Thanks.

Comment: That is came from the group by ID, if you remove the ID, then you will get count number.

Comment: When I remove the ID, I get the following error: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'DBO.OFD.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Please see the update script and let me know is that what you need?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.  I was able to successfully complete the script, on my own; which required me to create an additional temp table, and using count to select the information that I needed.  Although my question was not clear to everyone, with a little more research and effort, on my part, I was able to complete it.